# “Time” versus “Times”: When is time plural?

Tags: word-choice, idioms, grammatical-number, word-usage

I have difficulty in using time and times correctly.

I understand that times may be used for some idiomatic purposes such as "at all times" or "of all times" or "some times", although sometimes it will be in singular, as in "all the time".

My concern is not really about the meanings of the particular idioms in my examples. Instead, I want to know if there is any general rule that I may refer to when I am deciding whether to use time or times, for an idiom, nouns, or likewise.

Comment: Without an article, _time_ is a mass noun referring to the experience of duration: _Time and space are dimensions; In time, you'll come to realize_. With an article, _time_ is a count noun referring to an individual event. _The time we tore the goalpost down,What is the time now? At the same time; A time to remember._

Comment: "Our times have passed."

Answer (score 5):

> 1. How much time did you spend in Spain?
> 2. He punched me three times.

In the first  sentence *time* refers to the amount of seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks, years, decades, centuries, millennia and so on. This noun is uncountable.

In example (2) *times* refers to the number of occurrences. The number of instances that something happened. This is the same type of *time* as in "*I asked her three times*". That question doesn't mean, for example, I asked her for three hours! This noun is countable and usually used in the plural.

Comment: "New York Time**s**" How many "_occurrences_" of New York present in this magazine title?

Comment: @23W Yes, that's yet a different type of *time* (as in *that was before my time* or *The life and times of Grizzly Adams* etc (the answer being: more than 1!) There's probably a few more too.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/time_1
and other dictionaries show clearly "**uncountable**" for some of the meanings

Generally:

1. Instances/Occasions, recorded values for durations, etc: times
2. The abstract notion, and generally not 1: time

Comment: On the other hand, "You have to learn to change with the times" uses "times" in an abstract way—it means something like "prevailing worldview"—and yet the word is expressed in plural form.